# Область видимости Javascript

Tags: javascript, ооп, объекты, global-variables

К Примеру есть такой объект

```
Project.Module.Contact = {
    Init : function()
    {
        this.Validate();
    },

    Rules : 
    {
        // Code
    },

    ContactForm : $('#contact-form'),

    ResponseCont : $('#response-cont'),

    Validate : function()
    {
        this.ContactForm.validate(this.Rules);
        this.ContactForm.submit(this.FormSubmit);
    },

    FormSubmit : function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$(this).valid()) return;
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), this.AjaxResponse);

    },

    AjaxResponse : function(response)
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```

конечно, же он не будет работать, потому, что в "FormSubmit"
this нам даст саму форму и вот так : this.AjaxResponse не будет работать, можно обратиться так Project.Module.Contact.AjaxResponse так будет работать, но не думаю, что такие длинные строки писать хорошо, 
что можно сделать ?
как обратиться по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

один из вариантов использовать [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
Validate : function()
{
    this.ContactForm.validate(this.Rules.bind(this));
    this.ContactForm.submit(this.FormSubmit.bind(this));
},
```

Но тогда придется менять `FormSubmit`, так как сейчас этот метод *ожидает* jQuery объект вместо основного объекта.

Например так

```
FormSubmit : function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.ContactForm.valid()) return;
    $.post(this.ContactForm.prop('action'), this.ContactForm.serialize(), this.AjaxResponse);

},
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно объявить модуль через замыкание - это стандартный способ объявления модуля.

К сожалению, многие IDE до сих пор его не понимают.

```
Project.Module.Contact = function() {
  var module = {
    // ...
  }
  return module;
}()
```

Здесь создается функция, которая сразу же вызывается. Эта функция создает объект-модуль и сразу же его возвращает. Для чего это делается? А для того, чтобы получить дополнительную область видимости.

Так, внутри функции модуль предварительно кладется в локальную переменную `module` - а значит, его можно получить через эту переменную:

```
FormSubmit : function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).valid()) return;
    $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), module.AjaxResponse);
},
```

Также подобный трюк позволяет вводить закрытые переменные и функции модуля, недоступные снаружи - что позволяет уменьшить связность кода и избежать проблем с избыточными зависимостями модулей друг от друга.

К примеру, методы `FormSubmit` и `AjaxResponse` явно же нужны только для внутреннего использования, а значит и делать им в объекте модуля нечего:

```
Project.Module.Contact = function() {
  var module = {
    // ...

    Validate : function()
    {
        module.ContactForm.validate(module.Rules);
        module.ContactForm.submit(FormSubmit);
    },
  }
  return module;

  function FormSubmit (e)
  {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).valid()) return;
      $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), AjaxResponse);
  }

  function AjaxResponse (response)
  {
      // Code
  }    

}()
```